# Order array items by property and keep order of original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

I wrote this function to group an array by one or more properties:

```
var groupBy = function (fields, data) {
    var groups = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        var container = groups;
        for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
            var groupField = fields[j];
            var groupName = item[groupField];
            if (!container[groupName]) {
                container[groupName] = j < fields.length - 1 ? {} : [];
            }
            container = container[groupName];
        }
        container.push(item);
    }
    return groups;
};
```

For example if I use this input

```
var animals = [
    {type: "cat", name: "Max"},
    {type: "dog", name: "Charlie"},
    {type: "cat", name: "Zoe"},
    {type: "dog", name: "Abby"},
    {type: "cat", name: "Molly"}
];

var groupedAnimals = groupBy(["type"], animals);
```

I get this output:

```
{
    "cat": [
        {
            "type": "cat",
            "name": "Max"
        },
        {
            "type": "cat",
            "name": "Zoe"
        },
        {
            "type": "cat",
            "name": "Molly"
        }
    ],
    "dog": [
        {
            "type": "dog",
            "name": "Charlie"
        },
        {
            "type": "dog",
            "name": "Abby"
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything ok so far... the problem is that I need the keys to reflect the order of the original input-array. So if the first item was a cat, and I iterate over the group-keys I need the first key to be the cats as well. Since objects in JS are explicitly not ordered, I can not guarantee the correct order. How can I achieve that?

---

Edit:

I guess the result needs to be something like this:

```
groupBy(["type", "name"], animals)
```

should yield:

```
[
  {
    "group": "cat",
    "items": [
      {
        "group": "max",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "cat",
            "name": "Max"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group": "Zoe",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "cat",
            "name": "Zoe"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group": "Molly",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "cat",
            "name": "Molly"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "dog",
    "items": [
      {
        "group": "Charlie",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "dog",
            "name": "Charlie"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group": "Abby",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "dog",
            "name": "Abby"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You can't, you need an array to keep its content in some specific order. You can can create the iteration order by manipulating an array returned by `Object.keys`, though.

Comment: Don't' Maps keep the insertion order? If you used Maps instead of plain old objects here, that might get what you want?

Comment: I can't use maps... ES5 only :/

Comment: THAT is a pity. Then Object,keys is probably a useful suggestion.

Comment: @Teemu: In ES2015 and above, object properties do have an order. But using it is not generally a good idea.

Comment: please add a wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a completely dynamic function for grouping various keys and depth.

This proposal works with a hash table and an array for each level.

```js
function groupBy(keys, array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
            if (!r[a[k]]) {
                r[a[k]] = { _: [] };
                r._.push({ group: a[k], items: r[a[k]]._ });
            }
            return r[a[k]];
        }, this)._.push(a);
    }, { _: result });
    return result;
}

var animals = [{ type: "cat", name: "Max" }, { type: "dog", name: "Charlie" }, { type: "cat", name: "Zoe" }, { type: "dog", name: "Abby" }, { type: "cat", name: "Molly" }];

console.log(groupBy(["type", "name"], animals));
console.log(groupBy(["type"], animals));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your result data structure to array of arrays so you can keep order.

```js
var animals = [
 {type: "cat", name: "Max"},
 {type: "dog", name: "Charlie"},
 {type: "cat", name: "Zoe"},
 {type: "dog", name: "Abby"},
 {type: "cat", name: "Molly"}
];

var result = []
animals.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.type]) {
    this[e.type] = [e.type, []]
    result.push(this[e.type])
  }
  this[e.type][1].push(e)
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

To group by multiple fields you can pass array as first parameter to your function

```js
var animals = [
 {type: "cat", name: "Max", i: 2},
 {type: "dog", name: "Charlie", i: 2},
 {type: "cat", name: "Zoe", i: 2},
 {type: "dog", name: "Abby", i: 1},
 {type: "cat", name: "Molly", i: 2}
];

function groupBy(fields, data) {
  var result = []
  data.forEach(function(e) {
    var group = fields.map(a => e[a]).join('-')

    if (!this[group]) {
      this[group] = [group, []]
      result.push(this[group])
    }
    this[group][1].push(e)
  }, {})
  return result
}

console.log(groupBy(['type', 'i'], animals))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need this to work with multiple group-properties as well e.g. `groupBy(["type", "name"], animals);`... as far as I can see this method only works for a single level of grouping(?)

Comment: What is expected result for grouping by multiple fields?

Comment: I added an example as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could alter your function a tiny bit so that it adds a special property at each group level, which lists the keys in the order they should be iterated:

```js
var groupBy = function (fields, data) {
    var groups = { _keys: [] };
    //             ^^^^^^^^^
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        var container = groups;
        for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
            var groupField = fields[j];
            var groupName = item[groupField];
            if (!container[groupName]) {
                container[groupName] = j < fields.length - 1 ? { _keys: [] } : [];
    //                                                           ^^^^^^^^^
                container._keys.push(groupName);
    //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            }
            container = container[groupName];
        }
        container.push(item);
    }
    return groups;
};

var animals = [
    {type: "cat", name: "Max"},
    {type: "dog", name: "Charlie"},
    {type: "cat", name: "Zoe"},
    {type: "dog", name: "Abby"},
    {type: "cat", name: "Molly"}
];

var groupedAnimals = groupBy(["type"], animals);

console.log(groupedAnimals);

// Output types in order:
console.log('output types in fixed order:');
groupedAnimals._keys.forEach(function (key, i) {
    console.log(i, key, groupedAnimals[key]);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```